# How to Browser test a Vue.js app mocking API calls?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, testing

I have an app that uses Vue.js as Frontend and Spring-boot as Backend.

I want to "unit test" (or integration test, whatever you wanna call it) my views, using browser and selenium, but mocking API calls (ajax requests).

Which tools are recommended to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium testing is called Integration or End-to-End (E2E) testing. Unit testing is not done with Selenium, it is usually done with one of the following tools: Jest, Karma, Jasmine, Mocha, or Chai. (some of these are "expectations libraries", some of these are "test runners", some are both)

### Unit testing in Vue

[Please check out the Vue Unit Testing guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html). The community has strong preferences toward Jest currently, which means most of the tooling you can download for free is aimed toward people using Jest.

### E2E testing in Vue

The modern, recommended tools for e2e testing a Vue app are Cypress or Nightwatch. I would start with those. [Check out this article to get started.](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/04/01/vue-testing-unit-vs-e2e/)

If you still want to use Selenium, there is literally no difference between testing a normal web app and testing a Vue web app. This is because Selenium operates at the level of abstraction of the Browser, and doesn't care what network requests you make, what backend you use, or what frontend you use.

### Which one do you need?

Well, both. [This article will help guide you to choose between them, or to do both](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html#TheTestPyramid). There are tradeoffs to each. We recently ditched our e2e tests entirely in favor of writing more unit tests. It's been about 2 years, and it's going great

Comment: What about mocking API calls?

Comment: Mocking API calls can happen on many levels. Option 1: in-javascript mocking and unit tests. Mock out the service you will be calling via javascript. This happens in your unit tests.... Option 2: spin up a mock server before running your e2e tests. Downside: keeping your mock server in sync w your real server. Cypress (E2E framework) has a section about it: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Testing-Strategies